# Creating a Class, and writing methods for the STARS program

Tags: java, class, for-loop, data-structures, return-type

I have an assignment to code the methods of the intro "Stars" program. I have all of the for loops figured out to print out the designs, but writing the classes with them is where I get tripped up. I'm still very new to programming and I'm sure there are lots of silly mistakes in my code.

[Here's the Document of the Stars output](http://learnonline.unca.edu/pluginfile.php/362423/mod_resource/content/1/Stars.pdf)

```
public class STARS {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    public int rows;
    public String part1, part2, part3, part4, part5;

    public STARS(int rows){
    }

    private static String part1(int rows){

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int stars = 0; stars < rows; stars++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        return " ";
    }
    private static String part2(int rows){

        System.out.println("");
        for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
            for (int star = 1; star <= i; star++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        return " ";

    }
```

Comment: It's not obvious what your actual question is, could you make it clearer please?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class STARS{

public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int rows = scan.nextInt();
    part1(rows);
    part2(rows)
}

private static String part1(int rows){

 for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int stars = 0; stars < rows; stars++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println("");
 }
 return " ";
}

private static String part2(int rows){

    System.out.println("");
    for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
        for (int star = 1; star <= i; star++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    return " ";
    }
}
```

You really don't need a return type for the methods part1 and part2 because you are apparently returning an empty string.